# Async React.Component doens't work for me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I want to split my React app by chunks and have faced with a problem. `React.Component` don't render child `React.Component` that is loaded via `require.ensure`. The example code below.

File one:

```
let Child;
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
      super();
      require.ensure(['child'], () => {
        Child = require('child');
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!!Child && <Child/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

File two

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>hello world</div>;
  }
}

module.exports = Child;
```

And I retrieve the next error:

> Uncaught Error: Minified React error #130; visit
>   http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]=
>   for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full
>   errors and additional helpful warnings.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would recommend that you provide some form of content to React while the dependency is being loaded. I would recommend a loading message of some kind.
2. You need to ensure that the component is rerendered when loading is complete. The easiest way to accomplish this is to store the result of the `require` call in the component state, not in a global.

For example, your code might look something like this:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
      super();
      require.ensure(['child'], () => {
        this.setState({Child: require('child')});
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {'Child' in this.state ? <this.state.Child/> : "Loading..."}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've taken your advice and now I store `Child` component into `store`. But I faced with another issue  _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined_ in` <this.state.Child/>`. I think that problem occurs after minification of bundles.

Comment: This is a core React/Javascript feature. You have something incorrect with your setup, probably in your transpiler/minifier, which is not in any of the code you have pasted and it is difficult for us to identify.

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you to use es6 sintax, and set process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev'
for more helpful messages on errors and warnings

if you are using webpack try this [webpack-dev-server](http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#development-server)

File one

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import Child from './Child'

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Child/>
    )
  }
}
```

File two "Child.jsx"

```
import { Component } from 'react'

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello World</div>
    )
  }
}

export default Child
```

Comment: "Webpack doesn’t support ES6 modules; use require.ensure or require directly depending on which module format your transpiler creates." https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Answer (score 0):

Install `babel-pollyfill` in dev and add this line in your webpack configuration

```
entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/index'
  ],
```